How to set grant_type in Apache client HttpPost
List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://example.com");
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters, "UTF-8"));
httpPost.setHeader("HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION", "Basic "+base64encoded);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
tokenApiResponse = this.httpClient.execute(httpPost);
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"Token response:{0}",tokenApiResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

I am getting 401 unauthorized as status code.
Can someone please review the way I'm setting grant_type into HttpPost request?
I'm being a little skeptical there.
In linux, below is the piece with which I've achieved it:
curl --location 'https://dev1.erf.us-phoenix-1.ocs.oc-test.com/ords/erfp/oauth/token' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --header 'Authorization: ••••••' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'


Generally one should use HttpClient CredentialsProvider APIs and let the client generate the necessary headers automatically

Please also note that your java code is using BASIC auth, while it is unclear from the curl snippet whether it uses the same scheme

It is same, just that in curl command its masked.

Are you sure? If it is BASIC or BEARER auth, then you should rather let HttpClient generate the headers for you
